# Unable to run `sigh` fastlane

Tags: ios, hybrid-mobile-app, fastlane

on running `sigh` this is the error I get, any resolutions?

```
`download_certificate': Couldn't download provisioning profile, got this instead: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> (Spaceship::Client::UnexpectedResponse)


<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Try your request again.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="pics-label" content='(pics-1.1 "http://www.icra.org/ratingsv02.html" l gen true for "http://www.apple.com" r (cz 1 lz 1 nz 1 oz 1 vz 1) "http://www.rsac.org/ratingsv01.html" l gen true for "http://www.apple.com" r (n 0 s 0 v 0 l 0))'>
    <meta name="Author" content="Apple Inc.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/global/styles/ext/2.2/ext-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/assets/apps/styles/asst/1.0/xtheme-developer.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/assets/styles/base.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/assets/styles/adc.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/global/scripts/lib/prototype.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/global/scripts/lib/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/global/scripts/browserdetect.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/global/scripts/apple_core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/global/scripts/search_decorator.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/global/scripts/adc_core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/assets/styles/script.css" media="screen">')
    </script>
</head>
<body id="error">
    <div id="globalheader">
    <h1><a href="/">Apple Developer</a></h1>
    <ul id="gh-nav">
        <li id="gh-nav-technologies"><a href="/technologies/">Technologies</a></li>
        <li id="gh-nav-resources"><a href="/resources/">Resources</a></li>
        <li id="gh-nav-devcenters"><a href="/programs/">Programs</a></li>
        <li id="gh-nav-support"><a href="/support/">Support</a></li>
        <li id="gh-nav-membercenter"><a href="/membercenter/">Member Center</a></li>
    </ul>


</div>



    <div id="content" class="box">
        <div class="cap boxtop"></div>  
            <div class="msg warn">
                <h4>We are unable to process your request.</h4>
                <p>An unknown error occurred. Please <a href="index.action">try again</a>.
            </div><!--/msg-->
        <div class="cap boxbottom"></div>
    </div>

<div id="globalfooter">
    <p class="gf-buy">Shop the <a href="http://www.apple.com/store/">Apple Online Store</a> (1-800-MY-APPLE), visit an <a href="http://www.apple.com/retail/">Apple Retail Store</a>, or find a <a href="http://www.apple.com/buy/locator/">reseller</a>.</p>   
    <ul class="gf-links piped">
        <li><a class="first" href="/sitemap/">Site Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="/rss/">RSS Feeds</a></li>

    </ul>   
    <div class="gf-sosumi">
        <p>Copyright &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> Apple Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
        <ul class="piped">
            <li><a href="http://www.apple.com/legal/terms/site.html" class="first">Terms of Use</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.apple.com/legal/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div><!--/globalfooter-->
</body>
</html>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spaceship-0.14.1/lib/spaceship/portal/certificate.rb:256:in `download_raw'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/lib/sigh/runner.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_profiles'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/lib/sigh/runner.rb:80:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/lib/sigh/runner.rb:80:in `block in fetch_profiles'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/lib/sigh/runner.rb:77:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/lib/sigh/runner.rb:77:in `find_all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/lib/sigh/runner.rb:77:in `fetch_profiles'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/lib/sigh/runner.rb:20:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/lib/sigh/manager.rb:7:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/bin/sigh:34:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:428:in `run_active_command'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:68:in `run!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/bin/sigh:89:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sigh-1.1.3/bin/sigh:107:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/sigh:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/sigh:23:in `<main>'
```

summary:

```
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                     Summary for sigh 1.1.3                     |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| adhoc                         | false                          |
| skip_install                  | false                          |
| development                   | false                          |
| force                         | false                          |
| app_identifier                | com.test.mobile.v1             |
| username                      | abc@gmail.com                  |
| output_path                   | .                              |
| skip_fetch_profiles           | false                          |
| skip_certificate_verification | false                          |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: I get similar error for `cert` command as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work, All I had to do was set the `sigh` parameters in my lane and turned off the `skip_certificate_verification` flag. Not really sure why this would cause or fix this error, but everything is working as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and solved it by making the account an Admin in the Apple member center. Being just a "Member" seems to fail the download for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

From the body of the unexpected response you received it seems like the issue was related with the Developer Portal, rather than the tool itself.

The fact that you report having issues with both `sigh` and `cert`, both attempting to connect to the Developer Portal, is a plus one to this hypothesis.

During November iTunesConnect and the Developer Portal had some problems, and might also had been down at a certain point.

This is going to sound unhelpful, but I would suggest to make sure fastlane and its dependencies are up to date, and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

This issue affects both an older version of cert and sigh.

Most probably the version of sigh/cert/spaceship you used was [trying to download certificates it didn't have access to](https://github.com/fastlane/cert/issues/13). This happens in particular when your user has only Member rights on some projects.

The issue was corrected in cert 1.2.8, released early 2016.

As for sigh, it [appears to be still broken](https://github.com/fastlane/sigh/issues/260).

So right now, you could work around this by skipping validation of the certificates, or changing your user roles in the developper center.

In the future, hopefully you should be able to upgrade sigh and it should work.